# How to submit form data using POST with no name for unique value

Tags: javascript, forms, post, dataset

When generating a form using Javascript to post into an iframe, how to POST a single string as value without any attribute name attached to it?

I have this output (In Google Chrome console):

> **Form data:**
>
> **data:** "{'color': 'blue', 'shape': 'circle'}"

when I am actually looking for:

> **Form data:**
>
> "{'color': 'blue', 'shape': 'circle'}"

My code:

```
    var f = document.createElement("form");
    var i = document.createElement("input");
    i.setAttribute('type',"text");
    i.setAttribute('name',"data");
    i.setAttribute('value',"{'color': 'blue', 'shape': 'circle'}");
    f.appendChild(i);
    f.submit();
```

Note that I cannot use regular Xhr Calls at this is a cross domain task.

Comment: Why not just have two input fields with the associated name and value? `i1.setAttribute('type',"text");
i1.setAttribute('name',"color");
i1.setAttribute('value',"blue");
i2.setAttribute('type',"text");
i2.setAttribute('name',"shape");
i2.setAttribute('value',"circle");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you are trying to deliver a `data/json` payload using an HTML form. This is impossible, an HTML form can only send data with one of three encoding types (controlled by the `enctype` attribute on the form), `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (the default format for POST), `multipart/form-data` (necessary when doing file uploads), or `text/plain` (obsolete, don't use this).

Using AJAX won't help either, cross-domain AJAX is limited to doing exactly what an HTML form can, unless the server sends an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

If you have control over the server, you can change the format it expects the data in (or send an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, but that is supported by fewer browsers). If you don't, you can setup a simple API on the server you serve the Javascript from to pass requests through to the other server. Even a simple PHP script would be enough.

Comment: Thanks @wingedsubmariner. I was trying to avoid the API route but it looks like they wont be any other alternative